# Given a function, is it linear or not and why?

Tags: signals

Hello stack overflow community. Given this function I just need to know if this function is linear or non linear.
**y[n] = (n-3)x[n+3]** system is linear or not?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a programming question. Check out http://math.stackexchange.com/.
Or even https://www.wolframalpha.com/ for simple questions like these.

Answer (score 0):

Not the right place to ask this at all, that said:

Non-Linear:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph:+y(n)+%3D+(n-3)(n%2B3)
Obvious because it has a curve.

Comment: Thanks you and sorry for that. but for the function i mean y[n] = (n-3)x[n+3] , where x[n+3] is the input , it is not a multiplication. So the answer would be linear I think.

Comment: Yes that is linear then